# How to make separate custom configuration file for <defaultDocument> from web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I would like to move defaultDocument from web.config to separate config file.
Please let me provide any solution.

```
<defaultDocument>
    <files>
        <clear/>
        <add value="login.aspx"/>
    </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your web.config specify a `configSource` for your `defaultDocument` section:

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument configSource="default.config" />
</system.webServer>
```

Then, in your configuration file containing the `defaultDocument` section:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<defaultDocument>
    <files>
        <clear/>
        <add value="login.aspx"/>
    </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

Note that VisualStudio will not propose you the `configSource` attribute, but it will work.

To test with VisualStudio, simply launch your WebSite then remove any page from your URL path and you should be redirected to your default document specified in your configuration file.

Comment: i tried this solution but configSource it through the  configSource attribute not allowed

Comment: It's a warning by VisualStudio, not an error. You can ignore this warning and try it.